# WM_SYSCOMMAND with wParam 0xF063?

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc, wm-syscommand

I am trapping [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) messages in WinForm in a C# application for reasons that are not relevant. Sometimes, my handler receives a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message with the **wParam** `0xF063`.

There is no *0xF063* in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Passing it to the base Form class's **WndProc** seems to close the window, which I suppose makes sort-of sense as the **wParam** is **almost** `0xF060` (the `SC_CLOSE` message).

So... what exactly is this `0xF063` message, and what distinguishes it from the normal `SC_CLOSE`? Why even have it if it seems to do the exact same thing as `SC_CLOSE`? There seems to be no documentation regarding this value.

Comment: Does this help: #define SC_CLOSE_OPEN 61539 // 0xF063 Close and Popup already opened, see https://github.com/manuelcalerosolis/Gestool/blob/master/prg/Window.prg

Comment: What does "Close and Popup already opened" mean though (as opposed to simply "Close")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is the SC_CLOSE command.  From the MSDN article for WM_SYSCOMMAND:

> In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator.